# How to set a System Entity in a JSON response?

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have a composite entity working fine. But when I try to change its value by another composition in fulfillment, it's been interpreted as a string value:

```
const entity = {
                  "name":"projects/myproject/agent/sessions/" + sessionID + 
                  "/entityTypes/lia_parametro1",
                     "entities":[{
                             "value":"@sys.email:email",
                               "synonyms":[
                                            "@sys.email:email"
                                           ]
                                              },
```

When I put this value directly in Dialogflow Console(@sys.email:email) it works fine, but when I try to do this dynamically as above, it understands "@sys.email:email" as a value, instead of a System Entity.

Is there a special way to declare System Entities in Json format?

Many thanks for any tip!

Diego Mesquita

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting confused about what the purpose of entities are.

Entities are used when extracting parameters - they're hints to Dialogflow to say "I'm trying to grab a piece of data from whatever the user has said, by the way the piece of data I want you to extract looks like *this -> [the values of @sys.email]*".

When something reaches your fulfillment code, that whole data extraction process has been done, and therefore entities become irrelevant. You can run whatever code you wish to extract data (for example a regex), then assign that as a parameter value to some output context.

To quote [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/entities-overview):

> Each intent parameter has a type, called the entity type, which dictates exactly how data from an end-user expression is extracted.

I hope this helps - if not, can you give a little more info about your use-case?

Comment: Hi @James King!  Thanks for your reply! I do understand the purpose of entities. Actually, all code of my case is working,except by the above scenario were I have 2 dynamic cases: the entity and the type of the entity. In fact, they are generated dynamically according to the parameters of a third part system, an the reason by which I'm not able to generate a session entity containing a System entity as a reference is a bug!  Thanks!